# binary search with restriction how many times one Object is the outcome

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a sorted Array of a custom class. This class implements the Comparable interface and is sorted with the java.util.Arrays.sort(Object o) method.

My Problem is that i search trough the Array via java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Object o). Multiple times. Lets say 1000 times. But i want to limit that the same resulting index is only five or ten times in the results.

With linear Search im able to do this easily by using a second Array to save how many times an index is used. If it exceeds the given maximum the next best matching index is used.

My Question is if it is even possible to implement something like this with binary search without breaking the runtime of O(log n).

Example:
The list: `[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10]`
My Method:

```
public int getBestMatchingIndex(int i, int[] array){
   int result = Arrays.binarySearch(array, i);
   if(result >= 0)
            return result;
        
   int insertionPoint = -result - 1;
   if(insertionPoint == 0)
      return insertionPoint;
   if(insertionPoint == Database.filesAndColors.length)
      return insertionPoint-1;

   return (array[insertionPoint] - i) < (i - array[insertionPoint -1]) ?
                insertionPoint : insertionPoint -1;
}
```

This Method gets called multiple times. Lets say 10 times. Each time with a different `int i`. Because this Method returns the best Matching index it can happen that one index is returned multiple times. Because this i want to limit the multiple return of one index to a given number. When this number is hit the second best matching index is used and so on.

Thanks in advance. And if some source code is needed just say so.

Comment: What do you mean, "only five or ten times in the results"?  Do you just want to delete an element after it's found sufficiently many times?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't want to delete it. I just want that it cant be choosen again as a result of the binary search.

Comment: Binary search can generally only pick one element.  It doesn't really have a choice.

Comment: I feel you should avoid searching for an unwanted result. If it's just a matter of duplicates... Maybe give us an example and expected output.

Comment: @clwhisk Ive provided a more detailed version of my problem. Hope it can help.